# What is the most effective way to create BigInteger instance from int value?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a method (in 3rd-party library) with BigInteger parameter:

```
public void setValue (BigInteger value) { ... }
```

I don't need 'all its power', I only need to work with integers. So, how can I pass integers to this method? My solution is to get string value from int value and then create BigInteger from string:

```
int i = 123;
setValue (new BigInteger ("" + i));
```

Are there any other (recommended) ways to do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
BigInteger.valueOf(i);
```

Comment: Cool :) Didn't noticed that method myself.

Comment: I lost by a 6 seconds.. (I just made up that number).

Answer (score 8):

Use the static method `BigInteger.valueOf(long number)`. `int` values will be promoted to `long` automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this static method: `BigInteger.valueOf(long val)`

Answer (score 3):

```
setValue(BigInteger.valueOf(123L));
```